# Listing user checked categories with all categories in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am processing a user form that includes some categories its populated as check box in  my form

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="1"> CCTV &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="2"> Access Control &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="category[]"value="3"> Fire Alarm &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="4"> Intrusion Alarm System &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
```

I will store the category as comma seprated string in db like this way

```
$category=implode(',',$_POST['category']);
```

This sholud be  displayed in `view my category` page ,in this page i want to display all category with user selected category's  as checked  (ie **if user is `CCTV` category is selected it should be displayed as marked**),
but i don't know how to achive this??

Here is my code   it displaying all category without user checked value

```
<?php
//fetch user checked category from db and convert to array.
$user_cat=explode(',',$value['category']); //eg;array(5,6,8)
//all categorys value
$all_cat_value=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8');
$all_cat_txt=array('CCTV','Acess controle'....,'Fire alaram');

//populates all category with checked value
for each($all_cat_txt as $key=>$val){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$[$all_cat_value][$key].'">'.$val;
}
```

Note:Length of  `$all_cat_value` and `$all_cat_txt` is same

Comment: Try `in_arraay` http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Tips to improve :- Please keep single associative array for category value and text instead of using `$all_cat_value` and `$all_cat_txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `in_array()` and find checked value exist in array or not. If found then add `checked` property in checkbox.

```
//fetch user checked category from db and convert to array.
$user_cat=explode(',',$value['category']); //eg;array(5,6,8)
//all categorys value
$all_cat_value=array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8');
$all_cat_txt=array('CCTV','Acess controle',....,'Fire alaram');

//populates all category with checked value
foreach($all_cat_txt as $key=>$val){
    $checked = "";
    if(in_array($all_cat_value[$key], $user_cat))
    {
        $checked = "checked";
    }
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$all_cat_value[$key].'" '.$checked.'>'.$val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks let me try that